# Want to make batch file or package file for Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, caching, popup

I want to make a package or exe file for below points for IE.

1) Clear IE Cahche : I am using this command > RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255

2) Pop Up Blocker Off

3) Comparability View Settings Enable for all websites.

4) Reset Internet Explorer settings.I am using this file to reset > MicrosoftFixit50195.msi

Please help to make all these 4 in one package so that user just run the package and one by one it start and run.

Thanks.